# Hplip stop working in ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aadvark)

Tags: hp, 17.10, hplip

After updating to ubuntu 17.10, hplip 3.17.9 stopped working.
When trying to download and install latest version which is 3.17.10 I have this message

> error: ubuntu-17.10 version is not supported, so all dependencies may not be installed. However trying to install using ubuntu-17.04 version packages.

Is there any workaround that I can do while waiting for new updates?

Comment: You should try hplip from official repositories.

Comment: Did you mean using `sudo apt-get install hplip`?

Comment: Yes, I mean using `sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mistake!
Trying to install hplip application to manage my HP printers graphically I download the file `hplip-version.run` from the website and then I run it, instead of that I found that it would be very easy to use `sudo apt-get install hplip` (which will install a compatible version with your system).

Then I realized that instead of installing `hplip` wich will only install drivers for HP printers with no GUI, instead of that I should've intstalled `hplip-gui` by typing `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` witch will install the graphical interface alongside with the drivers.